# Prerequisites to get SQL cmd in computer

Tags: installation, sql

I want to get SQL cmd in my system. Could someone please guide me the complete steps? Even though I have a native client installed, sql cmd is still not appearing in the command prompt even by typing SQL cmd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables.  Double click on the PATH system variable in the bottom window.  You should have a value that looks like this:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\

That's where your SQLCmd would be and you need to add it to the path.

After a change to system enviroment variables you'll have to reboot in order to see them.

You can check your work at the command prompt C:> echo %PATH% and it should show up there.